# My uk visa got refused

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, refusal

I applied for a short term under 18 student visa but it was refused.

I am from Syria and have lived in UAE for the past 4 years. I finshed my gcse o-levels since I came from Syria. My English language was bad so I was struggling with my studies because I am studying the British curriculum.

I applied for a visa to do an English course in an accredited English school 1 month ago. I gave all the documents they wanted including a

- photo copy of my father's 5 years ongoing visa
- father's bank statement
- invitation letter from the English school
- letter from my current school in UAE that says I am registered for the next academy year
- letter from my dad

I was refused for the following reasons:

- I have not provided any evidence of previous English studying
- there are English courses in Egypt for less expense
- I didn't say how will the course help me in future

Also they said that I have been studying at an English curriculum school since 2011 and because I stated I am struggling so they said this contradicts with what I wrote.

At the end they wrote the following: that I am not satisfied that you intend to leave the UK at the end of your student visa.

Please answer and advise me on what to include in my future application

Comment: You should contact the school you were thinking of studying at, they will probably have seen other situations like yours and might be able to advise you.

Comment: I am puzzled by the reference to Egypt. If I wanted to improve my French as rapidly as possible, I would look for a French course in France, to combine immersion with instruction. Similarly, I would expect the OP to learn more English faster in England than in Egypt.

Comment: Not really, check e.g. http://www.aucegypt.edu - they have english courses.

Comment: @rbm aucegypt.edu even features on their home page "Learn about AUC's biggest classroom - Cairo.". Cairo would be an excellent classroom for learning certain dialects of Arabic, but not as good as e.g. London for learning English.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question answers itself. The ECO mentioned the reasons already why you were refused. If you apply again make sure you address all of those comment with STRONG reasons in your new application. Since you could not justify your course, the ECO thought you have an immigration intent.

Answer (score -4):

If they are not satisfied with your intention to leave the UK at the end of your student visa, maybe next time you apply, include a return flight ticket.

Comment: Tickets are not helpful.  The application guidance specifically instructs applicants not to submit them, so an applicant who does submit them is advertising a disregard of the guidance.  Why do they say not to submit tickets?  Because showing that you *have* a ticket is not the same as showing that you *intend to use* it.  An intending immigrant could purchase a round-trip ticket and discard the return portion; in many cases, this is even *less* expensive than buying a one-way ticket.

Comment: @phoog: proof of a return ticket is helpful, although not mandatory. It's a further bit of evidence that his intention is not to overstay his visa.. In this case it won't be enough to tip the balance to his advantage, I'm afraid.

Comment: @QuoraFeans how can it help your application to include something that you have been explicitly instructed not to include?

Comment: @phoog: the application instructs applicant not to include the ticket, but a proof of it it's fine. They are advised to be in possession of a return ticket. A few of the airline consolidation sites allow you to book a ‘proposed’ itinerary for the purpose of going back to it at a later date.  travel agents can 'block' a flight ticket for you without actually booking them and the details of this flight can be provided for you visa application

Comment: @QuoraFeans ECOs are explicitly instructed not to consider documents that are submitted in spite of their being on the "do not include" list.

Comment: @phoog: yes, but you are wrong at assuming that you never have to include travel booking/agent confirmation. The official source: https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf Just don't send the ticket itself.

Comment: @QuoraFeans yes, there is an exception: you should send bookings if you are specifically asked to do so. That circumstance is implied neither in the question not the answer, which incorrectly advises to send them in the absence of such a request. I am therefore beginning to suspect that you misunderstand the guidance. Furthermore, I don't understand what you mean by not sending the ticket itself: nobody gets paper tickets anymore, so doing that is essentially impossible.

Comment: @phoog: Two bits; Though e-tickets by far the norm for air travel, paper persists. It's pretty common to ask for travel confirmation. The OP was probably asked.